# How to check if eclipse workspace is locked

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several eclipse instances running at the same time and I want to check if a workspace from one of these instances is currently in use.
So I want to check it with just the knowledge of the path `C:\Users\XY\workspace` to the workspace.

I've seen that there is a `.lock` file in the `.metadata` folder. But its size is all the time `0 KB`. So how to check it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the `.lock` file exists there, then it is locked.

Comment: Nope, if i close my eclipse then the `.lock` file still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locking code `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.location.Locker_JavaNio` uses:

```
RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile(lockFile, "rw");

FileLock fileLock = raFile.getChannel().tryLock(0, 1, false);
```

to lock the `.lock` file.

The `tryLock` will throw an exception if the file is already locked.

Unlock is:

```
fileLock.release();

raFile.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hints. However this still does not answer the question. Maybe one could write a Java Program that could do the check with this info. But isnt there  a simple way to test it from command-line/shell-script? And why does Eclipse not simply delete the .lock file on exit?

Comment: @Jörg Command line on what operating system? I'm not an Eclipse designer so I can't say why it doesn't delete the lock.

Comment: I am on MacOS but I need to provide a solution from a platform independent bash script. It can of course use ${OS_TYPE} but should not need to launch a JVM. However, already a solution for MacOS would be great. https://github.com/devonfw/devon-ide/pull/32